# remove spaces between {}

Tags: java, regex

```
<#if  {   cntry  }  =  "FI"  >  <#if  {   addr2  }  =  " "  >" "  <#else> ${  addr2   }    </#if>  ${   addr1  }    ${   zipcd  }   ${   city  }      <#else> <#if  {   addr2  }  =  " "  >" "  <#else> ${  addr2   }    </#if>  ${   addr1  }    ${   addr2  }   ${   addr3  }    ${   cntry_desc  }  ok fine  </#if>
```

i want the output as

```
<#if  {cntry}  =  "FI"  >  <#if  {addr2}  =  " "  >" "  <#else> ${addr2}    </#if>  ${addr1}    ${zipc}   ${city}      <#else> <#if  {addr2}  =  " "  >" "  <#else> ${addr2}    </#if>  ${addr1}    ${addr2}   ${addr3}    ${cntry_desc}  ok fine  </#if>
```

just want to remove spaces between {}

Comment: SO, known around the world as the Ask Your Regex Here Site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\{\\s*", "{")
         .replaceAll("\\s*\\}", "}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use

```
\{\s+([\w]+)\s+\}
```

and use

```
{$1}
```

as replacement.

So, this code

```
String raw = "<#if  {   cntry  }  =  \"FI\"  >  <#if  {   addr2  }  =  \" \"  >\" \"  <#else> ${  addr2   }    </#if>  ${   addr1  }    ${   zipcd  }   ${   city  }      <#else> <#if  {   addr2  }  =  \" \"  >\" \"  <#else> ${  addr2   }    </#if>  ${   addr1  }    ${   addr2  }   ${   addr3  }    ${   cntry_desc  }  ok fine  </#if>";
raw.replaceAll("\\{\\s+([\\w]+)\\s+\\}", "{$1}");
```

will return

```
<#if  {cntry}  =  "FI"  >  <#if  {addr2}  =  " "  >" "  <#else> ${addr2}    </#if>  ${addr1}    ${zipcd}   ${city}      <#else> <#if  {addr2}  =  " "  >" "  <#else> ${addr2}    </#if>  ${addr1}    ${addr2}   ${addr3}    ${cntry_desc}  ok fine  </#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as `{` and `}` are not nested you can use this regex to search:

```
" +(?=[^{]*})"
```

And use this for replacement:

```
""
```

**Java Code:**

```
String repl = input.replaceAll(" +(?=[^{]*})", "");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tX5vT5/1)